# What material is Spider-man's web made of?

Tags: spider-man, marvel, the-amazing-spider-man, the-amazing-spider-man-2

Particular reference to *Amazing Spider-Man* 1&2 movies is appreciated

In movies, the web is too thin and it turns liquid after some time, It has very great co-efficient of elasticity and it can maintain huge tension forces on it.

**What material is it actually made of?**

Comment: In the comics, the webbing dissolves after a period of time as well (something like 2 hours).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Marvel.com](https://marvel.com/universe/Spider-Man%27s_Web-Shooters), in the comics, we see the web-shooters use web fluid, described as:

> a shear-thinning liquid (virtually solid until a
>   shearing force is applied to it, rendering it fluid) **whose exact
>   formula is as yet unknown, but is related to nylon**. On contact with
>   air, the long-chain polymer knits and forms an extremely tough,
>   flexible fiber with extraordinary adhesive properties. The web fluid's
>   adhesive quality diminishes rapidly with exposure to air. (Where it
>   does not make contact with air, such as the attachment disk of the
>   web-shooter, it remains very adhesive.) After about one to two hours,
>   certain imbibed esters cause the solid form of the web fluid to
>   dissolve into a powder. Because the fluid almost instantly sublimates
>   from solid to liquid when under shear pressure, and is not adhesive in
>   its anaerobic liquid/solid phase transition point, there is no
>   clogging of the web-shooter's parts.

which is first seen in Amazing Fantasy #15 (1962).  So, in the comics, it's more of a nylon material.

In the *Spiderman* trilogy (2002-7), this ability is described as:

> Organic Webbing Generation: In the Sam Raimi movie trilogy, Spider-Man
>   was also gifted with the ability **to organically produce his own silk
>   webbing from glands within his forearms**, limited by his body's health
>   and nutrition. **These organic webs have many of the same properties as
>   a spider**. Thanks to its similar properties, it appears Spider-Man can
>   utilize his organic webbing in any way he could with the artificial
>   webbing from the comics.

([Source](http://spiderman-films.wikia.com/wiki/Spider-Man_%28Tobey_Maguire%29#Powers_and_Abilities))

Conversely, in the movies it seems to be more like spider's silk.  So the answer is, **it depends which source you're focusing on.**